# Disable colour change when source list loses focus

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

When an item is selected in the source list it is highlighted in blue. When another element on the window is selected, however, the highlight becomes a lighter blue as the source list is no longer focused.

I would like to change the behaviour so the item is always the darker blue, the same behaviour as seen in Finder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the source list of Finder never become the fist responder, so, I guess that the first step is to subclass your table view or outline view, and implement the - (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder method

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}
```

It will make the selection of your source list always stay light blue, and you may use some undocumented methods such as _highlightColorForCell to change the highlight color.